# how to get the top 30 items in a list

Tags: c#, list

how can I get the top 30 items in a list in C# and add it to a new list?

I have a list of about a 1000 items, and want to create new lists, of about 30 items each, and then somehow bind the lists to listbox

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `LINQ` [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method:

```
var top30list = source.Take(30).ToList();
```

Add `using System.Linq` at the top of your file to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

everybody is saying linq so i'll show example without linq:

```
List<object> newList = new List<object>();

for(int i=0 ; i < 30 ; i++)
    newList.Add(oldList[i]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Take(30)

```
public List<string> ReturnList(List<string> mylist,int page)
{
    return mylist.Skip(30 * (page - 1)).Take(30)
}
```

Comment: Useful as is implied requirement is to get the top 30, followed by the next 30, etc. In that scenario the list.Skip() is required information.

Answer (score 4):

```
newList.AddRange(list.Take(30));
```

Answer (score 2):

use `orderby`with column name after that use as `.Take(30)` will select the 30 items from the list.